# Split a string with a character between curly braces

Tags: java, string, split

I have following string :

```
{"attribute1":"value1","attribute2":"value2","attribute3":{"attribute3a":"value3a","attribute3b":"value3b"}},{"attribute1":"value1","attribute2":"value2","attribute3":{"attribute3a":"value3a","attribute3b":"value3b"}},{"attribute1":"value1","attribute2":"value2","attribute3":{"attribute3a":"value3a","attribute3b":"value3b"}}
```

I need to split this string on "," between "}}" and "{" and put each result in a tab.

The result I want is :

```
tab[0] : {"attribute1":"value1","attribute2":"value2","attribute3":{"attribute3a":"value3a","attribute3b":"value3b"}}
tab[1] : {"attribute1":"value1","attribute2":"value2","attribute3":{"attribute3a":"value3a","attribute3b":"value3b"}}
tab[2] : {"attribute1":"value1","attribute2":"value2","attribute3":{"attribute3a":"value3a","attribute3b":"value3b"}}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: this looks like JSON. I'd take a look at a JSON reader rather than trying to parse it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solves your problem

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "{\"attribute1\":\"value1\",\"attribute2\":\"value2\",\"attribute3\":{\"attribute3a\":\"value3a\",\"attribute3b\":\"value3b\"}},{\"attribute1\":\"value1\",\"attribute2\":\"value2\",\"attribute3\":{\"attribute3a\":\"value3a\",\"attribute3b\":\"value3b\"}},{\"attribute1\":\"value1\",\"attribute2\":\"value2\",\"attribute3\":{\"attribute3a\":\"value3a\",\"attribute3b\":\"value3b\"}}";
        String[] output = input.split("},");
        for(String s: output) {
            System.out.println(s+"}");
        }
    }

}
```

However, this is not an elegant way of doing it. You should try parsing your input using JSON libraries

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. upvoting is the way of saying thanks here :-)

Comment: Yes, I know but I can't. When I click on up arrow, a popup tell this : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."
Sorry ! :/

Answer (score -1):

This definitely looks like JSON. I would suggest looking at this SO post on parsing JSON:
[How to parse json in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)